# Relation between Order of element and nature of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove or disprove : If every element of a group G are of same order then G is abelian . I am not getting how to show it. I can prove easily that  group having elements of order 2 only is abelian. But how to prove it generally ?

Comment: It is already false for $n=3$, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This question is closely related to the [restricted Burnside problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Burnside_problem): given numbers $m$ and $p$, is the restricted Burnside group $B_0(m,p)$ finite?

> Proposition: A finite group $G$ has the property that all non-trivial elements have the same order $p$ if and only if $p$ is prime and $G\ne 1$ is a quotient of $B_0(m,p)$ for some $m.$

Another counterexample is the following group:

$$G= \langle x, y, z  |   x^3=1,  y^3=1,  z^3=1,  [x,z]=1,  [y,z]=1,  [x,y]=z^{-1} \rangle$$
is non-abelian of order $27$, and all its non-trivial elements have order $3$.
The group is exactly the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{F}_3$ from Robert's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean every non-trivial element.

This is not true in general. A counter example can be found [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Unitriangular_matrix_group:UT(3,3)).